# How to hook into all database operations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Wondering if there is a way to create a trigger of some sort in PostgreSQL where you can listen for all modification queries on all records on all tables in a database. Basically watch everything in a database as it changes.

For example, it looks like MongoDB has this feature using [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/).

> Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog.

Wondering how the same sort of thing can be accomplished in PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding-explanation.html

Comment: You can set  log_statement = mod in the postgresql.conf. ie to only log modifications